# ios scroll webview to bookmark in pdf

Tags: ios, pdf, webview, scroll, bookmarks

my webview displays a pdf file that has bookmarks for certain pages. How to I get the code to automatically scroll to the page of a particular bookmark in the pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use iOS PDF viewers. (E.g. [FastPdfKit](http://fastpdfkit.com/))

Comment: hmm, thanks. I checked it out and there is no direct way to goto a bookmark, but you can get a list of bookmarks, and you can go to a certain page, so I assume that you could indirectly accomplish this by getting the page of a bookmark and going to the page. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again mohamede - you are really helpful.